# Don't catch SerialException at pySerial inWaiting()

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, pyserial

I work with Python3. My purpose is to write simple script, which may handle connect/disconnect and read data. I use pySerial library.

At initial stage of the script I have

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/rfcomm0')
```

Later I have the next code:

```
def readAndPrint():
    try:
       waitingChar = ser.inWaiting()
    except serial.SerialException as e:
         print("Got serial exception")
         portOpenFlag = False
         readException = True
    if (waitingChar > 0):
        print("Got some data")
        data_str = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        print(data_str)
```

Everything is fine till I read data, but when I close Bluetooth connection form another side I got

```
s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

and never actually arrive into *except serial.SerialException* case.
What is wrong?

**EDIT:** 
This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_scripts/serialTest.py", line 43, in <module>
    readAndHandleException()
  File "python_scripts/serialTest.py", line 36, in readAndHandleException
    readAndPrint()
  File "python_scripts/serialTest.py", line 22, in readAndPrint
    waitingChar = ser.inWaiting()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 435, in inWaiting
    s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback?

Comment: You are catching only the ``serial.SerialException`` type.  The exception actually being raised is ``OSError``, which is not a subclass of ``SerialException``.  Either you need to use a less specific type, or have multiple ``except`` clauses to catch both types.